# Dequeue emails in Postmark

Tags: postmark

I have a bunch of queued emails in Postmark that I would like to delete.  How can I delete/dequeue emails in Postmark?

I have tried searching the activity page for some sort of user interaction, but beyond listing the queued emails, there appears to be nothing I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the time this was asked, there is no way to do this.  You have to go through customer support.